# 3x3 matrix vector multiplication using GMP

Tags: c++, performance, gmp, bignum

I have a vector of large (upto 2048 bits) signed integers (f.a, f.b, f.c) and a 3x3 matrix of signed int64_t (aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc). I want to update (f.a, f.b, f.c) by multiplying with the said matrix. This happens many many times in my code, I have profiled and found out that the above steps take up a significant portion of my runtime.

Currently my code is the following

```
mpz_mul_si(faa, f.a, aa);
mpz_mul_si(fab, f.b, ab);
mpz_mul_si(fac, f.c, ac);

mpz_mul_si(fba, f.a, ba);
mpz_mul_si(fbb, f.b, bb);
mpz_mul_si(fbc, f.c, bc);

mpz_mul_si(fca, f.a, ca);
mpz_mul_si(fcb, f.b, cb);
mpz_mul_si(fcc, f.c, cc);

mpz_add(f.a, faa, fab);
mpz_add(f.a, f.a, fac);

mpz_add(f.b, fba, fbb);
mpz_add(f.b, f.b, fbc);

mpz_add(f.c, fca, fcb);
mpz_add(f.c, f.c, fcc);
```

I have tried doing all the individual multiplications and additions in separate threads and joining them (using std::thread) but that unspeakably slows down the performance. I thought it would be better to use addmul_ui and submul_ui [functions](https://gmplib.org/manual/Integer-Arithmetic.html) from gmp. However they turn out to be slower overall, although I am not sure why. Even a few percent improvement will help. The target hardware is:

Dell Inspiron 3670 64bit
i5 -8400 @ 2.8GHz
8GB ram
GPU: Geforce GTX 1060 3GB

Comment: Your code looks fine. Parallelizing at such a low level wouldn't make sense, you only want to start threads when they have a BIG amount of work to do. Maybe check for optimizations at a higher level?